# What is the best way to decode Ntrip 1.0 protocal using boost::beast

Tags: httpclient, boost-beast

I am currently using `boost::beast` to implement a ntrip 1.0 client. It has the request like:

> GET /BUCU1 HTTP/1.0 User-Agent: NTRIP GNSSInternetRadio/1.2.0
>   Authorization: Basic aHVnb2JlbjpodWdvYmVuMTIz

And the response like:

> ICY 200 OK

It has the non-standard http response.

I as the beast http client example code, it get this response in the buffer. But it generates a exception in the read function. The error is "Read, Bad version". I am wondering what is the best way to handle the non-standard http response.

```
void
    on_write(
        boost::system::error_code ec,
        std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

    if (ec)
        return fail(ec, "write");


    // Receive the HTTP response
    // boost::beast::flat_buffer buffer_; // (Must persist between reads)
    // http::response <http::string_body> res_;

    http::async_read(socket_, buffer_, res_,
        std::bind(
            &session::on_read,
            shared_from_this(),
            std::placeholders::_1,
            std::placeholders::_2));
}

void
    on_read(
        boost::system::error_code ec,
        std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

    if (ec)
        return fail(ec, "read");         // ex
}
```

Comment: This is addressed in this open issue: https://github.com/boostorg/beast/issues/595#issuecomment-334581721 I am currently working on something along these lines, it might go into Boost 1.68

Comment: Thanks. Vinnie. I think I have to parse those by myself since Ntrip 1.0 does not follow the http standard.

Comment: I"m working on something for this

Comment: That's great. Looking forward to your new update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished using the `icy_stream` class located in the experimental directory in the master or develop branches (https://github.com/boostorg/beast):

```
#include <boost/beast/experimental/http/icy_stream.hpp>
...
using http = boost::beast::http;
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;
...
boost::asio::io_context ioc;
http::icy_stream<tcp::socket> stream(ioc);
http::response<http::string_body> res;
...
http::read(stream, res);
```